# Can a flowchart end with a method rather than a stop?

Tags: flowchart

Can a java flowchart end with a method rather then a stop?

When my game ends, it calls a method to show the menu again, so I finish the flowchart with a subroutine box that calls the menu method, can this be possible or should a flowchart always end with a stop?

In the menu there is an option to exit the program so it is not an infinite loop.

---

*What I did:*

I created a simple hangman game, at first it outputs a menu (has a method of its own).

The menu has 3 options, Play game, Show score, Exit.

If the user plays the game and either loses or wins the game will take him to the menu which will give the user the same 3 options.

In my flowchart of the Play Game method I dont know if I can end the flowchart with calling the method that outputs the menu, rather than a stop function.

[image: Flowchart]

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what tools you're using? `flowchart` is a rather broad tag.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Michael, what do you mean by tools?

Comment: Well, for example, what are you referring to by "in the menu there is an option to exit". What menu? What programs, libraries, etc? There is very little context here except that you're writing this in Java. My guess is that you're using some kind of flow-based programming tool.

Comment: I created a simple hangman game, at first it outputs a menu(has a method of its own), the menu has 3 options, Play game, Show score, Exit, if the user plays the game and either loses or wins the game will take him to the menu which will give the user the same 3 options, in my flowchart of the Play Game method I dont know if I can end the flowchart with calling the method that outputs the menu, rather than a stop function, I would upload an image of the flowchart but it says that 10 reputation is required.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by Java Flowchart either. You can edit your question to include a link to a picture. Those with more reputation can insert the picture for you. Just press the `edit` menu below the question.

Comment: Flowcharts are a relict of the past, they are not very useful to describe modern event-based object-oriented programs.

Comment: I just need it for my school project.

Comment: Here is a link to the image, can it end like this? http://prntscr.com/7bhqzv